# How to select a Medical Research use case

Tags: google-fit

On the page https://developers.google.com/fit/policy?hl=en#appropriate_access_to_and_use_of_google_fit_apis it says the following:

> Do not use Google Fit APIs for applications, services, or features designed to collect or combine user data for human subjects research, medical research, or any other similar research overseen by an Institutional Research Board or Ethics Commission unless you receive prior written approval to such use from Google. Select a "Medical Research" use case during the scope access request process and you will receive additional information on how to proceed.

I'd like to use the Google Fit API for a medical research purpose, but I cannot find where I'd select the "Medical Research" use case. Can anyone show me where I can find this?

I'd be using the Google Fit API to start tracking steps on the user's Android device and read these steps.

Comment: No problem, I deleted my answer to keep your post clean ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Scope = Purpose of your medical research and used API scopes

I think it is rather misleading, in fact when Google documentation talks about medical research scope, they do not mean it at the API level.

**What they mean is that you have to state in your app registration application that you would be using your app for a "medical research purpose", along with the fit API scopes that you would be using for your medical research.**

You can read the [following link](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization) that describes the authorization process intended by Google, but I will will detail below how to proceed:

---

#### Enable Fitness API and create credentials

After [enabling Fitness API in your Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=fitness) for your project (create a new one if you haven't already) then you have to apply for verification and submit the relevant supporting information for why your app needs "Medical Research" scope (basically documents related to the purpose of your medical research, which University or Lab you are working for etc). This choice happens right after adding credentials to your project when you have to set up OAuth consent screen:

[image]

---

#### Filling the app registration form

Filling accurately will speed up the verification process

- On the first tab, you will likely have to provide a very solid application privacy policy link (stating which data you access and for which purpose):

[image]

[image]

---

#### Select your API scopes

- Then you will have to add the scopes (scopes as API) that you would need for the purpose of your medical research:

[image]

- The one you will need to read the steps is:

> *[scopes your app needs to request](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes#authorization_scopes).*

*`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read |   Read location data from the Google Fit platform. |  Restricted`*

[image]

---

#### Enter your Medical Research "Scope"

- Finally, and **this is where you provide all information related to your medical research**, in the optional info *- meaning optional for most users, but not so optional for medical research -* already briefly stated in your privacy policy link: Its purpose, how it is financed, by which entity, what data your will be using etc. Be as clear as possible as it will speed up the review process.
- Provide links about your university or company website, research papers that you have already published, or by yours peers related to the scope of your medical research:

[image]